# React compiled with problems antd

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, laravel-8, antd

There are always show errors when compiling but I have imported from antd I don't know what is the problem is.

These are the errors shown when compiling

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 130:85-95

export 'Popconfirm' (imported as 'Popconfirm') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 207:37-40

export 'Row' (imported as 'Row') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 209:40-43

export 'Col' (imported as 'Col') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 239:39-42

export 'Col' (imported as 'Col') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 256:39-42

export 'Col' (imported as 'Col') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 264:44-50

export 'Button' (imported as 'Button') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 282:48-54

export 'Button' (imported as 'Button') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 307:39-45

export 'Upload' (imported as 'Upload') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 314:41-47

export 'Button' (imported as 'Button') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/components/excelPage.js 340:39-44

export 'Table' (imported as 'Table') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/utils/editable.js 31:31-42

export 'Form' (imported as 'Form') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/utils/editable.js 78:44-53

export 'Form' (imported as 'Form') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./src/utils/editable.js 88:33-38

export 'Input' (imported as 'Input') was not found in 'antd' (module has no exports)
```

This is my code
excelPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table, Button, Popconfirm, Row, Col, Upload } from "antd";
import Icon from '@ant-design/icons';
import { ExcelRenderer } from "react-excel-renderer";
import { EditableFormRow, EditableCell } from "../utils/editable";

export default class ExcelPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cols: [],
      rows: [],
      errorMessage: null,
      columns: [
        {
          title: "NAME",
          dataIndex: "name",
          editable: true
        },
        {
          title: "AGE",
          dataIndex: "age",
          editable: true
        },
        {
          title: "GENDER",
          dataIndex: "gender",
          editable: true
        },
        {
          title: "Action",
          dataIndex: "action",
          render: (text, record) =>
            this.state.rows.length >= 1 ? (
              <Popconfirm
                title="Sure to delete?"
                onConfirm={() => this.handleDelete(record.key)}
              >
                <Icon
                  type="delete"
                  theme="filled"
                  style={{ color: "red", fontSize: "20px" }}
                />
              </Popconfirm>
            ) : null
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleSave = row => {
    const newData = [...this.state.rows];
    const index = newData.findIndex(item => row.key === item.key);
    const item = newData[index];
    newData.splice(index, 1, {
      ...item,
      ...row
    });
    this.setState({ rows: newData });
  };

  checkFile(file) {
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (!file || !file[0]) {
      return;
    }
    const isExcel =
      file[0].type === "application/vnd.ms-excel" ||
      file[0].type ===
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    if (!isExcel) {
      errorMessage = "You can only upload Excel file!";
    }
    console.log("file", file[0].type);
    const isLt2M = file[0].size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
    if (!isLt2M) {
      errorMessage = "File must be smaller than 2MB!";
    }
    console.log("errorMessage", errorMessage);
    return errorMessage;
  }

  fileHandler = fileList => {
    console.log("fileList", fileList);
    let fileObj = fileList;
    if (!fileObj) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: "No file uploaded!"
      });
      return false;
    }
    console.log("fileObj.type:", fileObj.type);
    if (
      !(
        fileObj.type === "application/vnd.ms-excel" ||
        fileObj.type ===
          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
      )
    ) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: "Unknown file format. Only Excel files are uploaded!"
      });
      return false;
    }
    //just pass the fileObj as parameter
    ExcelRenderer(fileObj, (err, resp) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        let newRows = [];
        resp.rows.slice(1).map((row, index) => {
          if (row && row !== "undefined") {
            newRows.push({
              key: index,
              name: row[0],
              age: row[1],
              gender: row[2]
            });
          }
        });
        if (newRows.length === 0) {
          this.setState({
            errorMessage: "No data found in file!"
          });
          return false;
        } else {
          this.setState({
            cols: resp.cols,
            rows: newRows,
            errorMessage: null
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  };

  handleSubmit = async () => {
    console.log("submitting: ", this.state.rows);
    //submit to API
    //if successful, banigate and clear the data
    //this.setState({ rows: [] })
  };

  handleDelete = key => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    this.setState({ rows: rows.filter(item => item.key !== key) });
  };
  handleAdd = () => {
    const { count, rows } = this.state;
    const newData = {
      key: count,
      name: "User's name",
      age: "22",
      gender: "Female"
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [newData, ...rows],
      count: count + 1
    });
  };

  render() {
    const components = {
      body: {
        row: EditableFormRow,
        cell: EditableCell
      }
    };
    const columns = this.state.columns.map(col => {
      if (!col.editable) {
        return col;
      }
      return {
        ...col,
        onCell: record => ({
          record,
          editable: col.editable,
          dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
          title: col.title,
          handleSave: this.handleSave
        })
      };
    });
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Importing Excel Component</h1>
        <Row gutter={16}>
          <Col
            span={8}
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              alignItems: "center",
              marginBottom: "5%"
            }}
          >
            <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <div className="page-title">Upload Farmer Data</div>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col span={8}>
            <a
              href="https://res.cloudinary.com/bryta/raw/upload/v1562751445/Sample_Excel_Sheet_muxx6s.xlsx"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
              download
            >
              Sample excel sheet
            </a>
          </Col>
          <Col
            span={8}
            align="right"
            style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}
          >
            {this.state.rows.length > 0 && (
              <>
                <Button
                  onClick={this.handleAdd}
                  size="large"
                  type="info"
                  style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}
                >
                  <Icon type="plus" />
                  Add a row
                </Button>{" "}
                <Button
                  onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                  size="large"
                  type="primary"
                  style={{ marginBottom: 16, marginLeft: 10 }}
                >
                  Submit Data
                </Button>
              </>
            )}
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <div>
          <Upload
            name="file"
            beforeUpload={this.fileHandler}
            onRemove={() => this.setState({ rows: [] })}
            multiple={false}
          >
            <Button>
              <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload Excel File
            </Button>
          </Upload>
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Table
            components={components}
            rowClassName={() => "editable-row"}
            dataSource={this.state.rows}
            columns={columns}
          />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
```

editable.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Form, Input} from 'antd'

const EditableContext = React.createContext();

const EditableRow = ({ form, index, ...props }) => (
  <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
    <tr {...props} />
  </EditableContext.Provider>
);

export const EditableFormRow = Form.create()(EditableRow);

export class EditableCell extends React.Component {
  state = {
    editing: false,
  };

  toggleEdit = () => {
    const editing = !this.state.editing;
    this.setState({ editing }, () => {
      if (editing) {
        this.input.focus();
      }
    });
  };

  save = e => {
    const { record, handleSave } = this.props;
    this.form.validateFields((error, values) => {
      if (error && error[e.currentTarget.id]) {
        return;
      }
      this.toggleEdit();
      handleSave({ ...record, ...values });
    });
  };

  renderCell = form => {
    this.form = form;
    const { children, dataIndex, record, title } = this.props;
    const { editing } = this.state;
    return editing ? (
      <Form.Item style={{ margin: 0 }}>
        {form.getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: `${title} is required.`,
            },
          ],
          initialValue: record[dataIndex],
        })(<Input ref={node => (this.input = node)} onPressEnter={this.save} onBlur={this.save} />)}
      </Form.Item>
    ) : (
      <div
        className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
        style={{ paddingRight: 24, minHeight: 32 }}
        onClick={this.toggleEdit}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const {
      editable,
      dataIndex,
      title,
      record,
      index,
      handleSave,
      children,
      ...restProps
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <td {...restProps}>
        {editable ? (
          <EditableContext.Consumer>{this.renderCell}</EditableContext.Consumer>
        ) : (
          children
        )}
      </td>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall and re-install `ant-design`

`npm uninstall antd` and `npm install antd`