# Antd create form

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native, antd, ant-design-pro

Form.create() is not working on antd v4. How to make this code executable at antd v4

```
const EditableRow = ({ form, index, ...props }) => (
  <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
    <tr {...props} />
  </EditableContext.Provider>
);
export const EditableFormRow = Form.create()(EditableRow);
```

I change to this also cannot

```
export const EditableFormRow = () => {
    const { form, index, ...props } = useForm();
      return (
        <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
          <tr {...props} />
        </EditableContext.Provider>
      )
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look through docs that mention migrating to v4. of ant design form:

https://ant.design/components/form/v3

Comment: I read it before and change the code to export const EditableFormRow = () => (
    { form, index, ...props }) => (
        <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
          <tr {...props} />
        </EditableContext.Provider>
); but still not working

Comment: As it says you shouldn't use `export const EditableFormRow = Form.create()(EditableRow);` on v4. I just looked through

Comment: @ 
Mukhriddin Shakhriyorov yes,so I change to export const EditableFormRow = () => ( { form, index, ...props }) => ( <EditableContext.Provider value={form}> <tr {...props} /> </EditableContext.Provider> ) but also not working

Comment: could you share source code here?

Comment: @ 
Mukhriddin Shakhriyorov  I couldn't share it here, it is too long,  you could go to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70765502/react-compiled-with-problems-antd/70766524#70766524 and the code is the editable.js

Comment: @ 
Mukhriddin Shakhriyorov
I still struggled at this problem could u please help me

Comment: Look at there) I commented